# Display uyvy data in Qt

Tags: qt, rgb, v4l2

I have input source as DVD player with video format as UYVY.I want to develop a Qt application which takes UYVY data as input and displays the video frame.I used v4l2 Linux commands in Qt for capture and Qt widget to display video frames. I guess Qt QImage class does not accept UYVY format,it only accepts RGB .So how do i convert my data to RGB? Is there any other method ?? Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I just found QVideoFrame which supports UYVY http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoframe.html maybe there is some way to convert to QImage from that with use QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat

```
QVideoFrame cloneFrame(frame);  
cloneFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly);   
const QImage img(cloneFrame.bits(),   
                 cloneFrame.width(),   
                 cloneFrame.height(),  
                 QVideoFrame::imageFormatFromPixelFormat(cloneFrame .pixelFormat()));
...
```

Comment: Actually i implemented the yuv to rgb conversion matrix to my received buffer,but my function is pretty slow,i cant get the desired 25fps throughput. Maybe I should give QVideoFrame a try.

Comment: In my case I was using gstreamer which was providing GstBuffer with UYVY content. I changed gstreamer caps to format=BGRA and added one videoconvert element and set image format to Format_RGB32 and it just worked. I don't know if you are using gstreamer for v4l2